# How to create a line chart indicating which month a user wrote more or less blogs?

Tags: django, chart.js

This is how I want the output -

[image]

According to the above chart, the user wrote lots of posts between March and April, and then in the month of July the number is decreased.

I worked with tables and pie charts but couldn't make this one work. Here is a sample of the Django model can be used  for this purpose:

```
class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=160)
    ...
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I know the data to be used here can be extracted from `created_at` field but I don't know how to do the `JavaScript` part. If I pass `{"blogs": Blog.objects.all()}` context in template how do I plot above like line bar. Please help.

Thank You.

Comment: So you want the number of blogs grouped by `cleaning_at__month`?

Comment: yes, indicating that user posted how many blogs in which month but using a line chart

Comment: the screenshot looks like chartjs, see [here](https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/logarithmic/line.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are working on Django, I would draw this graph with [plotly](https://plotly.com/python/).

In your views.py:

```
import plotly.offline as pyo
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import datetime as dt
import calendar



time_values = Blog.objects.all().order_by("created_at")

time_values = [ element.created_at for element in time_values ]

time_values = [ element.month for element in time_values ]



published_amounts = [ 1 for element in time_values ]

new_time_values = [ time_values[0] ]
published_amounts = [ 0 ]

j=0

# the cycle prevents mixing months from different years
for i in range( 1, len(time_values) ):

    if time_values[i]==time_values[i-1]:
        published_amounts[j] = published_amounts[j] + 1

        
    else:   
        new_time_values.append(time_values[i])
        published_amounts.append(1)        
        j=j+1


new_time_values = [calendar.month_name[element] for element in new_time_values ]      
        

post_line = go.Scatter(
                    x=new_time_values, 
                    y=published_amounts,
                    mode='lines+markers',
                    name="Published posts",              
                    )

data = [ post_line, ]  

layout = go.Layout(showlegend=True, )

fig = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

plt_div = pyo.plot(fig, output_type='div')

context_dict={
        "plt_div":plt_div
                }

return render(request, 'your_page.html', context_dict)
```

Then in your template you simply have to put

```
{{plt_div}}
```

where you want your graph to be displayed.

Comment: thank you for taking the time and answering. I am getting this error `'int' object is not callable`  from this line `time_values = [element.month() for element in time_values] ` I tried other ways but they didn't work.

Comment: Remove () after month

Comment: I did that previously but I keep getting errors. `list index out of range` in ` if time_values[i] == time_values[i]: ` line.

Comment: I think now it works. copy and paste my answer again please.

Comment: Thank you brother, I tagged `chart.js` because I was expecting it from chart.js. This is a nice solution but lacks a bit explanation because I never used `potly` before,  but thank you anyway.